# Executing a list of functions for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am writing an import tool that will compare a user-selected .csv file to an existing table which then outputs a list of functions to be run on the file before it can be saved.  The comparison tool works, but then outputs the list of functions as strings:

```
print(func_list)
['func2', 'func4', 'func5']
```

I've tried the following, found here on SO to try to convert these strings into callable objects:

```
class classthing: 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        
dct = {name: classthing(name) for name in func_list}
func_list = [classthing(s) for s in func_list]
```

I'd like to run something to the effect of:

```
for func in func_list: result = func(df)
```

Here is an example of one of my functions:

```
def func2(dfname):
       dfname.ID_NUM='A'+dfname.TAIL.str[-9:]
```

Comment: What about `func_list = [globals()[s] for s in func_list]` instead of  `func_list = [classthing(s) for s in func_list]`?

Comment: That did it thanks